# Failure run labelImg on Windows

Tags: labelimg

labelImg command gives me the following error on my installation and I am unable to figure out a fix for the problem.

OS: Windows
PyQt version: PyQt5
Python version: 3.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "labelImg.py", line 1649, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "labelImg.py", line 1645, in main
    app, _win = get_main_app(sys.argv)
  File "labelImg.py", line 1638, in get_main_app
    args.save_dir)
  File "labelImg.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.use_default_label_checkbox = QCheckBox(get_str('useDefaultLabel'))
  File "labelImg.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    get_str = lambda str_id: self.string_bundle.get_string(str_id)
  File "D:\Study\LV\rice_payment_support\venv\labelImg\libs\stringBundle.py", line 47, in get_string
    assert(string_id in self.id_to_message), "Missing string id : " + string_id
AssertionError: Missing string id : useDefaultLabel
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you making changes to labelImg and having trouble understanding why your changes aren't working? Or are you just using labelImg? If just using, then this qustin belongs on superuser.com since it is not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed this links installation for labelImg
https://blog.roboflow.com/labelimg/

from the terminal install labelImg

```
>pip3 install labelImg
```

then run

```
>labelImg
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i just spend 2 days for solved this issue..
and how i solve this issue just `update microsoft store..`

i know thats crazy but its work.

OS : Windows 11

Python : Python3.7

anaconda